# How to call a function before returning from main function

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to clone a repo to a temp path and then when everything else is done and when returning from the main function, the program calls a function to delete the cloned repo from the temp path. How do I do this?

```
namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tempPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);

            // Clone a repo to the tempPath and something else
        }

        internal static void ProgramExit()
        {
            // Delete the clond repo from the tempPath
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've drastically changed the question, but it still just sounds like you're asking how to call a method in C#.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  The code is already calling a variety of other methods, what stops you from calling this method?

Comment: @David: Sorry for the confusion. It is a huge main function with several return point. What I wanted was when the program hits return or when the program gets to the last line of code, before it exits, it should call a particular function. I would like to see if there is anyway to do it without adding ProgramExit() before every signle return?

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather potent code smell, but you can use `try..finally` to achieve some sort of an automatic call regardless of early returns:

```
try
{
    // your code here
}
finally
{
    ProgramExit(...);
}
```

Comment: Hi Blindy, sorry for the confusion. I edited my question and I would like to clone a repo to a temp path and then when everything else is done and when returning from the main function, the program calls a function to delete the cloned repo from the temp path. How do I do this?

Comment: @AliZe198: Exactly as the answer shows - use a `try`/`finally` statement in `Main`, where the `finally` block calls your cleanup code.

Comment: @Blindy: Would it work if an exception was thrown?

Comment: Yes, it's a `try` block